# Make a c# application that runs continuously

Tags: c#, .net, windows, rest

I am writing a client side app that pushes data from users computers up to a website. I want this application to update the website every 60ish seconds. Right now I have my function wrapped in an infinite while loop with a 45 second sleep. But, windows says the application is not responding even though its updating the website. Here is how my code is structured.

Comment: You're not supposed to sleep on the main UI thread. The most straightforward approach is to use a [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) - (or that's one approach, at least).

Comment: so I would have a background worker the code every 45 seconds?

Comment: You could do that, yes - e.g. have a timer that fires off a background worker task every 45 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your while loop is *blocking the UI thread*. To fix this, you need to run your code on a separate thread.

The easiest way to do this to start off.. might be to use a `Timer`:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(45000); // timer will execute every 45 seconds

timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
    // your upload code here
};

timer.Start();
```

You should definitely look into Threading at a later stage though. Perhaps a `BackgroundWorker` or the Task Parallel Library.

Comment: I was also wondering if I could put all my code in the Program.cs file  instead of form1.cs and then call that from the ui every 45 seconds with a timer?

Comment: @ElliotWeil That is essentially the same. But if I had to make a suggestion.. I would not put it in `Program.cs`. Create a new class and call that. Since this code obviously doesn't need nano-second timing accuracy.. then either `Timer` is fine.

Comment: Awesome I'm going to give that a try and see if I can get it working. Also do you have any good examples of how to setup background workers? Not really sure how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: You were provided with the MSDN link in the comments above. Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx.

Comment: Thanks! I just think MSDN documents sucks(I'll do some googling) :( Going to report back soon after I modify my code.

Comment: @ElliotWeil You are right.. they are pretty bad at explaining things from scratch. Only once you have a basic grip on them do the examples become useful. Good luck!

Comment: So I moved all all my code into a seperate class but I'm having trouble getting the timer to worker and I'm not sure not that timer code runs every 45seconds. updating code above.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep(...)` *blocks* the UI thread for the number of specified milliseconds. One approach is to use `Task.Delay(..)` to not block the UI thread, but rather wait 45 seconds concurrently:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    running = true;

    while (running)
    {
        //your code

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4500);
    }
}
```